# Humidifier Fill indicator blinking when it has plenty of water

Tags: humidifier

I have a Kenmore Quiet Comfort humidifer that I've had for I don't know how many years.

Today I replaced the filter, and after I restarted it the F indicator was flashing, which is supposed to mean that the water reservoir is empty and I need to refill the water bottle. But I did refill it, so I guess I must have damaged or blocked a sensor while I opened it to change the filter.

The manual's troubleshooting section doesn't say anything about this case, it just says to fill with water when this blinks.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Might be something as simple as a loose or disconnected wire.  They are usually the easiest things to check after you changed something.

Comment: Look for a float that measures water level. Something resting on it could cause that issue.

Comment: @crip659 Doesn't seem to be electrical. I found the contact that the float presses against, and when I press it by hand the Fill indicator turns off.

Comment: Pictures of the various bits (float, contacts, water tank, etc) as well as an exact model number might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the float is sticking (can happen if you have hard water and deposits build up on it) or the switch the float operates is not connected. Since the humidfier is "I don't know how many years" old, hard water build-up would be likely.

Some sort of acid descaler (vinegar, citric acid solution, or a more expensive descaler product) should help to clean that off and allow the float to operate freely again. You'll have to look and see if you can find the float and its associated switch wires to observe if the float does not move freely due to build-up, or if you need to investigate further for an electrical cause.

Comment: I noticed when I was scanning the manual yesterday that iut recomends bi-weekly cleaning with a vinegar solution to remove scale, and cleaning the base with bleach, and I've never done this in all these years.

Comment: I added some extra water to the base, now the fill indicator is off. So maybe the float was sticking and needed extra water pressure to make it push the contact all the way. I'll see what happens as the base drains. Meanwhile I'll buy some vinegar the next time I'm out.